# Continuously checking two NSSecureTextField

Tags: xcode, cocoa, macos, passwords, nsimage

how can i make this to keep checking all the time the 2 NSSecureTextFields to know if they are equal/different to display the images without the need of a button?

the .h file:

```
IBOutlet NSSecureTextField *textField;
IBOutlet NSSecureTextField *textField2;
IBOutlet NSImageView *imagem;
}

- (IBAction)verificarPass:(id)sender;
```

the .m file:

```
- (IBAction)verificarPass:(id)sender;
{
    NSString *senha1 = [textField stringValue];
    NSString *senha2 = [textField2 stringValue];
    NSImage *certo;
    NSImage *errado;
    certo = [NSImage imageNamed:@"Status_Accepted.png"];
    errado = [NSImage imageNamed:@"Error.png"];

    if ([senha1 isEqualToString:senha2]) {
[imagem setImage:certo];
}else{
    [imagem setImage:errado];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a target method to the textField controls, triggered by the `UIControlEventEditingChanged` control event:

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(verificarPass:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Comment: i'm sorry, but i'm really new to this and i don't know how to make that :x can you tell me please?

Comment: @pedro, copy and paste the above line in the viewDidLoad method of your view controller .m file, after [super ViewDidLoad]

Comment: Note that the code specified above is correct for iOS, but not for OS X.